# Escaping html in xml

Tags: html, xml, escaping

I am facing a problem about invalid **XML** character occurring on web service interaction with **SOAP**.

With a specific web service, I send a message formatted html but in a certain case of that I got a failed message as following.

```
Fault message :
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#xF;" is an invalid XML character.
```

What does `&#xF` character reference? even I wrapped this message with `<![CDATA[ and ]]>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: As the error message clearly states, this has nothing to do with HTML. When you create XML need to escape your literal data properly, no matter the source. You should edit your question and specify what programming language you use to generate that XML and what your *relevant* code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reference to `&#xF`, but have a look on [this page](http://konfiguracja.c0.pl/webpl/encje.html), its in polish but you can find NCR for html/javascript...